# How can I change the background color of the footer of my UITableView inside UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

Sorry, I can't post picture here due to reputation.
The footer of the tableview inside a normal UIViewController is white color(default) but the whole Tableview is a gray color and this causes a strange look.

If I remove the Bounce Vertical, the white area will not appear anymore. But that means I cannot use pull to refresh.

So, I would like to know, how can I change the color of the white area?

Comment: You can upload the image to dropbox and share the link here

Comment: if you are not using viewForFooter just change tableView background color:     tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

Answer (score 0):

Please try to modify the backgroundColor of your tableview or its superview (that is controller's `self.view` if you add the tableview as controller.view's subview), or you can just implement `viewForFooterInSection:` to customize a footer view. I found there is not a default color if you have not set a footer.

Comment: Thanks,the problem was fixed.